# Probability that the smallest number obtained when two fair dice are rolled is 4?

Tags: probability

**You roll a red die and a blue die, both fair and independent. Find the probability that:**

1. The smallest number on either die is 4

The solution given for #1 is $\frac {5}{36}$. However, shouldn't the answer be $\binom {2}{1} \frac{2}{6} \frac{1}{6}$. Since on one of the die it can only get 5 or 6 thus $\frac{2}{6}$, and the 2nd die needs to be 4 thus $\frac {1}{6}$ ?

2. The numbers on the dice sum to 7

For question like #2. I only know how to get the answer by writing out all the possiblities i.e. (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) ... I was wondering is there another more conceptual way to do probability questions like #2?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: for this kind of problems, it's good manner to number the dies to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $1,$ you've overlooked the case where both are $4$.  In $2,$ whatever number 
 $n$ is on the red die, the blue die must show $7-n$

Comment: thank you I get it now, I misunderstood the wording of the question

Answer (score 1):

$\text{case 1 }-:(4,5)(4,6),(5,4),(6,4),(4,4)$

Hence Required probability$$=\frac{5}{36}$$

$\text{case 2 }-:(1,6)(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)$

Hence Required probability$$=\frac{6}{36}$$